# Help ID this Chris King NoThreadSet Color

Tags: identify-this-bike, headset

Can anyone help me ID the color of this Chris King NoThreadSet? And what year this color was offered?

[image]

Source: http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/chris-king-steelset-headset/rp-prod2035

Comment: I was going to guess the color is named '10 years of hard use orange'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Chris King: This is their SteelSet (stainless steel version of their popular NoThreadSet) in Brown. They release limited quantities every year.

Comment: It used to be Matte Bronze, but they've changed the name.